# Collision resolution/path finding between many object in Vampire survivours type of game

Tags: game-physics, game-development, collision, path-finding

So I'm making a vampire survivor clone. The base idea is many enemies (which are, simply speaking, just circles) are chasing out player, and they have to find the path in some way.
You can imagine the same type of problem with RTS games.
I'm aware of multiple workarounds, like:
Use A* and treat other enemies as obstacles. Doesn't work perfectly tho, it's relatively computation heavy considering the simple goal + other enemies are simultaneosly moving, which means they can disrupt each other path.
[image]
Circle collision resolution. Simpe and all, but again: by pushing one circle out of another, it can collide with a third one
[image: a collides with b and then with c]
I'm wondering what is the **BEST** (the most accurate) way, and what is the **easiest** way, which seemingly achievies the result.